# SSO logout function error "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: php, single-sign-on, adfs

I am filling in for a backend developer but I am a frontend developer. Hence the question: when I logout from a platform with sso, I get the error: object reference not set to an instance of an object. I know which function is giving the error, and that is the following:

```
function getAdfsSignOutUrl($adfsConf, $context) {
    $url =
    $adfsConf->adfsUrl.
    'Home'.
    '?wa=wsignout1.0'.
    '&wct='.gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', time()).
    //'&wtrealm='. $adfsConf->spIdentifier.
    '&wtrealm=http://www.xxx.be'.
    '&wctx=ssologoff'.
    '&wreply=http://xxx.xxx.be/index.php?page=authentication&action=loggedout';
    //'&RedirectAfterLogout='.urlencode($adfsConf->redirectLogoutUrl);

    return $url;
}
```

Can someone please elaborate to where I need to look? (probably a stupid question)

Thanks for the helping hand in advance.